# Is there a comoving nondimensionalization of the Fisher-KPP equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am considering the Fisher-KPP equation in the following form:

$$
\frac{\partial u }{\partial t'} = D \frac{\partial^2 u}{ \partial x'^2} + \rho u(1-u)
$$

Now, with the nondimensional variables:

$$
t= \rho t',\\
x = \sqrt{\frac{\rho}{D}}x'
$$
I can write the equation in nondimensionalized form:
$$
\frac{\partial u }{\partial t} = \Delta u  + u(1-u)
$$
I think I understand it until here. The Fisher-KPP equation allows for traveling wave solutions, so that it can also be written in co-moving form:

$$
0 = \Delta u +u(1-u) - v\nabla u
$$
**Is it possible to introduce a nondimensionalization that directly leads to this comoving formulation?** All the material I could find merely re-scales the variables by a reference quantity, but I have not found anything with co-moving transformations. I tried to use $x =  x' -vt$, but v does not even show up in the original formulation. What is the clean way to do this?